# Map texture to single points rather than quads?

Tags: opengl, shader, vertex-shader

Using OpenGL, is it possible to apply a fragment shader to a specified region around a single vertex i.e. glPoint, rather than creating an array of quads and mapping a texture coordinate of a "duck" to each vertex?

I guess it would be more efficient as it would only require one vertex to be sent to the GPU per duck displayed, rather than the four vertices currently needed.

I have achieved a similar effect by using a geometry shader to build a quad around each vertex. Still, I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same result without using a geometry shader.

I played around with gl_PointSize, but it is a limited feature, and I don't think it is the proper way to do it.

To summarize, I would like to know if OpenGL would allow filling a region around a single vertex using the fragment shader rather than, expressively creating a quad. Is that possible?

Comment: there might be some obscure way of doing it with some advanced shader knowledge, but it definitely wouldn't be more "efficient" in any way. Just because there are less vertices doesn't mean it's more optimized/efficient. If efficiency/optimization is what you are seeking, avoid complex shaders and stick to UV mapping.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I am not sure how to formulate my question because GPU philosophy is still complicated to understand. The bounds of the geometry are precisely defined by the edges (the vertices). Sometimes, especially in my question, I would like to extend the fragment shader at an offset from the geometry. If this geometry is a single point. the region would be a square around it.

Comment: My suggestion would be to create 2D rectangle objects in the scene for each duck, assign textures with alpha channels onto the rectangles, and resize the actual objects during runtime if you need to resize the ducks dynamically.

Comment: @Lilith it is what I am currently doing. I got better results (displaying 1'000'000 ducks at 60 fps), using the geometry shader to generate the rectangle from single points.

Comment: Actually you can draw a point with a large size using [`gl_PointCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader) for the texture coordinate.

Comment: @Rabbid76: "large size" is a bit of a misnomer, as they are limited by GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE, which is implementation-defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course. But since he don't want to generate the primitives, this is the only solution I can sink of.